# Handle back button actions inside android fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

i needed to override the default back button behavior so that i could go to the previous fragment instead of closing the entire application.

Below is the implementation of this function

```
class DataFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var fragment: Fragment
private lateinit var fm: FragmentManager
private lateinit var transaction: FragmentTransaction 

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    @Nullable container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner,object : OnBackPressedCallback(true){
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            fragment = PreviousFragment()
            fm = parentFragmentManager
            transaction = fm.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment)
            transaction.commit()
        }
    })
return binding.rootView
 }
}
```

Comment: If you use ``addToBackStack()`` in your transactions where you navigate to a new fragment, the back button will step back through them (that's what the back stack is for)

Comment: Thank you this approach is much better and cleaner. could you add it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, no worries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[When you perform a `FragmentTransaction`](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#using), you can call [`addToBackStack`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) to put that transaction on the back stack. When the user hits the back button, the last transaction on the stack is popped off, and all the changes in that transaction are reverted.

So if a transaction `replace`s *Fragment A* with *Fragment B*, and also `add`s *Fragment C*, popping that transaction with the back button (or `popBackStack()`) will undo that and restore it back to how it was, with just *Fragment A*. So you can build up specific history states the user can step back through (like a web browser) and control exactly what the back button does.

You can also provide a label with `addToBackStack` (use null if you don't care),
and then call [`popBackStack`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#popBackStack(java.lang.String,int)) with that label to jump back to that transaction (or the one before it) in one go. So you can create a workflow where the user can back through steps one at a time, or hit a button that jumps right back to a specific step you've marked, like the start of some task, or an overview, etc

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface OnBackPressedListener {
    /**
     * register and implement OnBackPressedListener in fragment 
     * @update status onBackPressed() from Activity to current fragment to handle super.onBackPressed(); or to continue next process
     */
   void onBackPressed();
}
```